# Vs Code for React-Native : is it possible to manually link libraries?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, linker, libraries

I have a problem with a library installed with npm command.
After hours of testing on searching a solution on the web, it seems that automatic Link failed. That is the reason why the classes I try to use do not work.

I work with Vs Code under a Windows system, and the only solution I found is for Mac: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#manual-linking

I found the XCODE file and the Libraries folder, but I can't find the windows shown after these steps.

So do you know if there is an equivalent tutorial for Windows and Vs Code ?

Thank you by advance !

Comment: unfortunately, no ... you need XCode for ios manual linking

Comment: oups, ok, thank you